# XCode 4 and Cmd + Shift + E shortcut doesn't work anymore

Tags: xcode, netbeans

guys.

I want to know if it is possible to make the Cmd + Shift + E (in XCode 3.x, this shortcut was used to maximize the editor window) works in XCode 4.

P.S: the idea is exactly the same as Cmd + ESC on Netbeans.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Xcode" - "Preferences" - "Key Bindings" - set it to whatever you want.

Full screen is <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. You can search for "zoom" or "full" and bind whatever key you want to whichever command you want (I wasn't entirely sure if you wanted "full screen" or just "Window" - "Zoom" command. Unfortunately, <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is taken as short cut, so if you really want to use that key, you may have to remove it from that particular "Use Selection for Replace" command:

[image]